# Proof of the Recriprocal/Quotient Rule for Limits, not understanding why we choose to divide by 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

[This proof](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/limitproofs.aspx#MathJax-Element-77) and others I've looked up for
$$ \lim_{x\to c}\frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{L} \quad\text{assuming $L$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x) \neq 0$ }$$

pick $\epsilon$ at $\frac{|L|}{2}$

$$0<|x−a|<\delta_1 \rightarrow |g(x)−L|<\frac{|L|}{2}$$

and at $\frac{|L|^2\epsilon}{2}$

$$0<|x−a|<\delta_2 \rightarrow |g(x)−L|<\frac{|L|^2\epsilon}{2}$$

This works out later in the proof when we are able to multiply $\frac{1}{|L|}$ by the reciprocal of the first equation, $\frac{2}{|L|}$, by the second equation $\frac{|L|^2\epsilon}{2}$ giving us $\epsilon$:

[image]
My question is, why do we pick epsilon at $\frac{|L|}{2}$ and $\frac{|L|^2\epsilon}{2}$, when we could (I think) pick them at $|L|$ and $|L|^2\epsilon$, which should later provide:

$$\frac{1}{|L|} \cdot \frac{1}{|L|} \cdot |L|^2\epsilon = \epsilon.$$

My understanding is the $\epsilon$ can be any real number greater than 0, and, $|L|$ must be a positive number, so why not use the combo above.. what rule is being broken or ignored?

Comment: Any positive numbers are fine

Comment: I think I know what you mean by "picking $\epsilon$ at ...", but I find it unsettling to see it expressed that way. I **think** what you mean is that you replace the $\epsilon$ in the definition of $L=\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ with other numbers; but the word "pick" suggests "set equal to", and I'm sure you do not intend that $\epsilon = \lvert L\rvert^2\epsilon/2.$ The page you cited just applies the definition of $L=\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ without mentioning $\delta$ or $\epsilon$, though the name $\delta_1$ is clearly meant to remind us of the $\delta$ in that definition.

Comment: Thanks David.  I said "pick" because I saw another proof say "Assert $\epsilon$ = ..." Specifically the quotient proof on this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Limits#Algebraic_Operations

Should I phrase it as "replace $\epsilon$"?

Comment: The notice at the top of that page, "This page may need to be reviewed for quality," is not kidding. And with the number of times the author of that section wrote "contrived," In wonder if they even believe the proof themselves. Your first link is much better style, though it assumes you are so familiar with the definition of a limit that you don't actually need to see "$\delta$" and "$\epsilon$" in order to recognize an application of the definition.

Comment: If you find it too hard to follow the logic [in your first reference](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/limitproofs.aspx#MathJax-Element-77), I suggest writing the definition of $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ using $\delta_1$ and $\epsilon_1$ instead of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$; then, in the context of your proof, you can set $\epsilon_1$ to anything you like, such as $\epsilon_1=\min(\lvert L\rvert/2,\lvert L\rvert^2\epsilon/2).$ You should not assert anything about "$\epsilon$", which in that context is supposed to be a number that is given to you.

Answer (score 1):

After "doing a little more rewriting", you have a fraction $\frac{1}{|g(x)|}$ on the right hand side.

You need to get rid of that $\frac{1}{|g(x)|}$ on the right hand side.

You can do that if you can find an upper bound for the positive quantity $\frac{1}{|g(x)|}$. Equivalently, you would like to find a positive lower bound for the quantity $|g(x)|$.

The one thing you know about $|g(x)|$ is that $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)=L$. *This* is what you are going to use to get a positive lower bound for $|g(x)|$.

*Question:* Knowing that $L \ne 0$, and therefore $0 < |L|$, what's your favorite positive number between $0$ and $|L|$?

*Answer: Of course* your favorite is $\frac{|L|}{2}$.

We now have a useful implication:

> If $|g(x)-L| < \frac{|L|}{2}$ then $|g(x)| > \frac{|L|}{2}$.

To put this implication to work, let $\epsilon = \frac{|L|}{2}$. Since $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)=L$ it follows that there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $|x-c| < \delta_1$ then $|g(x)-L| < \epsilon = \frac{|L|}{2}$. It follows that $|g(x)| > \frac{|L|}{2}$, and therefore $\frac{1}{|g(x)|} < \frac{2}{|L|}$.

And now I think you can finish the proof.

Comment: Am I correct in stating in my answer why your 'favorite number' shouldn't be chosen to be $|L|$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, because that would provide a totally useless bound of $|g(x)|>0$.

Comment: So sometimes you DONT want things to cancel out in math lol

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly because of this step?  If we choose $\epsilon$ at $|L|$ instead of $|L/2|$ it seems impossible to complete this step:

[image]

This would imply though that there are an infinite number of epsilons, different recripocal fractions you could take to prove so long as you avoid the $|L|$ cancelling situation here.  $\frac{|L|}{2}$ is the simplest fraction that works, so it makes sense they chose that.